# How can I access the Amplify environment name in my React app using React Amplify and the Amplify CLI

Tags: environment-variables, aws-amplify, aws-cli, aws-amplify-cli

I'm developing a React app using AWS Amplify (version 4.3.43) and the Amplify CLI (version 10.0.0). I need to access the Amplify environment name in my app.

I've tried adding it to an environment file using the following code in my amplify.yml file:

```
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - export AMPLIFY_ENV=$USER_BRANCH
        # Add amplify env variable to .env file
        - echo "REACT_APP_AMPLIFY_ENV=${AMPLIFY_ENV}" > .env
        - npm ci
```

However, sometimes $USER_BRANCH is empty. Is there a better or alternative way to achieve this?